# cucumber plant leaves turing yellow, brown and dying

Tags: plant-health, cucumbers

I live in New Mexico where its been over 100 each day.

My cucumber plant was growing very healthy for a few weeks now. I do regularly 
watering. It grew about 8 full sized cucumbers already.

All of a sudden a few days ago the leaves started turning yellow and dying.

The plant had tons of baby cucumbers flowering which are now shriveling up and dying. There was also a weird white powder at the base of the cucumber.

[image]
[image]

Comment: i live in new mexico where its been over 100 each day. how often and how much should i be watering?

Comment: Then maybe not too much watering. Could be rodents or insects eating the roots. You should show us one of these "white spots" also. But you can only post 2 pictures. I suggest you remove the second picture, and include a close-up of the cucumber inside that one, and post it again.

Comment: Welcome Jason! You now have enough rep to post as many pictures as you need. Hopefully that will help you get good answers to your question!

Answer (score 2):

Cucumbers need light intensity in the range of 10,000-20,000 lx and exceding this optimum causes premature senescence of the plants, meaning they age rapidly and then they die. Provide a little bit of shade for your plants if light intensity is too high.

Also, temperatures above 90°F (32°C) causes the plants to age earlier. My guess is that high temperature wouldn't age your plants so rapidly if the light intensity was in the specified range.

Answer (score 2):

Your cucumber plant may not be dying. Slight yellowing and browning is normal during summer time. Help your plant by cutting off these yellow and brown leaves immediately.